# Redirect a user to the page associated with the ID number they submitted

Tags: php, url, input, hyperlink

I'm fairly new to the PHP coding scene and require a jump-start...

I have a simple page asking the user for an ID number and would like the PHP file to recognise that number's associated URL and take them to that page.
I know how to use the form results directly in the URL but I would like to keep other URLs hidden from the user so they can only access what their code redirects them to.

*Example: User gets code "A1B2C3" and enters it in the field given. When they press submit I would like it to go to `http://website.tld/subdirectory/`*

It would be a bonus if the list associating each code to a URL could be a separate file.

Current code fragment I have

```
website.tld/entry.php?ID=
$_GET['ID']
switch($_GET['ID'])
{
    case: 101: $redirect = "/page1"; break;
    case: 202: $redirect = "/page2"; break;
    case: 303: $redirect = "/page3"; break;
}
header("location:".$redirect);
exit;
```

Comment: Any code examples of what you currently have would be helpful in providing you an answer.

Comment: $_GET['ID']

switch($_GET['ID']){

case: 101: $redirect = "/view/page1"; break;

case: 202: $redirect = "/view/page2"; break;

case: 303: $redirect = "/view/page3"; break;

}

header("location:".$redirect);

exit;

Comment: Sorry for it being on block. Not too sure how to split lines.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Instead edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way is to use an array and readfile:

```
$mycodes=Array ("A1B2C3"=>"http://website.tld/subdirectory/"
    ,"GLG"=>"http://www.google.com");

if(!empty($_REQUEST['sitecode'])){
    readfile($mycodes[$_REQUEST['sitecode']]);
}
```

You can put the array in a separate file and inlcude it.

Comment: Thanks, Gunni.
I hadn't even thought of this function.
Perfect as it allows me to use a CSV file to read from :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to do so, setting up a simple database seems highly beneficial in this situation. Then make a table something like:

```
users
user_id | user_site | attribute1 | attribute2 | ...
```

Where user_id is the unique identifier and user_site is the URL you'd like to redirect them to. Then you can look up each user by their entered ID and get the URL for that ID.